# Redirect in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want to Rewrite URL so that everytime when I type:

```
https://mywebsite/wp-admin/add_coupon
```

to get the page:

```
https://mywebsite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add_coupon
```

Comment: Did you try it via your .htaccess file ?

Comment: Sure. This is what I want, and I tried, but did not succeeded.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/admin/(.+)$ /admin.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]